# How to handle out parameters in a gmock mocked method

Tags: c++, tdd, googlemock

I have a method that will take an out argument(i.e reference to uint64_t) How can I mock this in Gmock? Also, upon a call to this method, I want to set the value of the passed-in reference to something I desire. Can this be achieved with Gmock?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here's a minimal example:

```
struct Iface {
    virtual ~Iface() = default;
    virtual void foo(uint64_t& a) = 0;
};

struct Mock : public Iface {
    MOCK_METHOD1(foo, void(uint64_t& a));
};

TEST(MockTest, TestSetArgReferee) {
    uint64_t some_val = 0;

    Mock some_mock{};

    EXPECT_CALL(some_mock, foo(testing::_)).WillOnce(testing::SetArgReferee<0>(42));

    some_mock.foo(some_val);

    ASSERT_EQ(42U, some_val);

}
```

The key here is `SetArgReferee` that sets i-th argument of `foo` (indexed from 0, so `SetArgReferee<0>` sets 1st arg of the mock method, `SetArgReferee<1>` sets 2nd arg etc.). See the [cookbook](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#mocking-side-effects-mockingsideeffects) for more info.